# Flask client-side session cookie not saved

Tags: python, flask, session

I have an question regarding Flask and it's integrated Client-Side session.

Context:

I have an domain `example.com` which is a homepage that is some javascript static webpage.

Under that same domain I have another VM that is running a Flask application under the name `service.example.com`.

Now when a user goes to the `example.com` webpage a script downloads content from `service.example.com` that GET request from `service.example.com` set-s a client-side session cookie. But it is not saved for the user who is visting `example.com`. Only when I directly go to `service.example.com` that cookie is set.

How can I set the cookie for the client who who is visiting `example.com`?

```
# example flask code I am using
from flask import session

session['custom_cookie'] = "blaah"
```

---

In my 'Inspect' -> 'Network' -> GET REQUEST FROM services.example.com -> Cookies, I have the following:

```
custom_cookie
path    "/"
samesite    "Strict"
secure  true
value   "eyJjYXB0Y2hhX2Nvb2tpZSI6IjEwNWVmMDI5LTk0NmUtNDYyOS05ZDBmLWE3N2YxZjM2MjdlNSJ9.ZSQEUw.BaaKBjCYDcALgaFUJGMw9iOyJKs"
```

But under 'Storage' -> 'Cookies' There is nothing set.

(I am using firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are usually scoped within its parent domain. Browsers do not support cross-site resource sharing by default for security reasons. However, you can script an API endpoint in `service.example.com` that will fetch desired session data and call it using AJAX on your `example.com` domain.